# Hello, I am getting two errors for textFieldDidChange ( Swift)

Tags: swift, compiler-errors, uikit, textfield

Can someone please help me out? I am getting these two errors

> use of unresolved identifier

and

> use of local variable textFieldDidChange before its declaration

Here is my code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Setting text field delegates
    emailTextField.delegate = self
    passwordTextField.delegate = self

    // Disable login button until both textFields are not nil
    textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange), for: UIControlEvents.editingChanged)
}

func textFieldDidChange() {
    if (emailTextField.text?.isEmpty)! || (passwordTextField.text?.isEmpty)! {
        print("text is empty")
        loginButton.isEnabled = false
        loginButton.alpha = 0.33
    } else {
        loginButton.isEnabled = true
        loginButton.alpha = 0.55
    }
}
```

**Edit**
Question has been answered however I noticed the button would enable after I typed into the first textField. So I changed the && to || because I wanted the button to be disabled until both textFields weren't empty. Just for anyone who has this issue as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `textFieldDidChange` method should be outside the `viewDidLoad` and should be *prefix-ed* with `@objc` since it is a selector.

```
class YourClass: UIViewController {

    // Your code

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       // Setting text field delegates
        emailTextField.delegate = self
        passwordTextField.delegate = self
        // Disable login button until both textFields are not nil

        emailTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange), for: UIControlEvents.editingChanged)
        passwordTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange), for: UIControlEvents.editingChanged)
    }

    @objc func textFieldDidChange() {
        if (emailTextField.text?.isEmpty)! && (passwordTextField.text?.isEmpty)! {
            print("text is empty")
            loginButton.isEnabled = false
            loginButton.alpha = 0.33
        } else {
            loginButton.isEnabled = true
            loginButton.alpha = 0.55
        }
    }

}
```

And the target should be added to the respective text fields - `emailTextField` and `passwordTextField`.

Comment: I did not downvote mate, thank you for your answer/ teaching as it worked! I will accept the answer as soon as I can.

Comment: @Clint _someone_ downvoted a few mins into posting the answer. I was referring to them. :) They have reverted it since.

Comment: @Clint you can accept only one answer for a question. FYI, the other answer is wrong :)

Comment: Opps! Yeah I didn't read your comments on the other one, thanks again mate. You're good to go.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri: how can you say other answer is wrong

Comment: @RakeshaShastri: I don't need to any explanation from you.. Keep it up Thank you

Comment: @RakeshaShastri: I am also upvoting for you

Comment: @JogendarChoudhary sir, i have explained as a comment in your answer. You missed adding targets to the text fields which should respond to the editing change.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri: Keep it up sir

Answer (score 1):

You have missed to place `"}"` for `viewDidLoad` method

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
   // Setting text field delegates
    emailTextField.delegate = self
    passwordTextField.delegate = self
    // Disable login button until both textFields are not nil
    textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange), for: UIControlEvents.editingChanged)

}



   @objc func textFieldDidChange() {
         if (emailTextField.text?.isEmpty)! && (passwordTextField.text?.isEmpty)! {
             print("text is empty")
             loginButton.isEnabled = false
             loginButton.alpha = 0.33
         } else {
             loginButton.isEnabled = true
             loginButton.alpha = 0.55
         }
     }
```

Comment: This would not work. You need to have @objc for selectors. Also you have to add targets to the required textfields for them to respond to the selector.

Comment: Thanks mate for your response and answer. Adding  emailTextField and passwordField.addTarget under viewDidLoad also did the trick. But your answer pretty much answered why I was getting one of the errors. Also I needed to add @ojbc for selectors

Comment: @RakeshaShastri: Thank you, For this xcode will auto suggest So no need to worried. btw Thank you

Comment: @JogendarChoudhary xcode will suggest adding targets to the username and password text field?